# Article in "something from France"

Tags: grammaire, articles

"I brought something from France for you."

> J'ai apporté quelque chose **de France** pour vous.
>
> J'ai apporté quelque chose **de la France** pour vous.

Which one is correct? We say "Je viens de France" without article, but "C'est au nord de la France" with article.

Comment: Also: http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#58_strong-em-noms-gographiques-et-leurs-articles-em-strong